# gnuplot troubles - getting double plots

Tags: gnuplot

I have a script I wrote that selects a block from a data file based on a command line argument. Up until now it has worked just fine. Now the graphs I'm getting out for the first 26 blocks have two sets of data in them. The data file should have about 190 blocks of data. I've thought and probed for an hour and I still have no idea why this might be happening. Here is the gnuplot script.

```
gnuplot << EOF
reset
set terminal png small size 1280,480
set output "graph_$1.png"
set yrange [-0.5:5.5]
set autoscale x
set lmargin 17
set label "SPILL" at -1,.5 right
set label "ON" at -1,1 right
set label "OFF" at -1,0 right
set label "DATA" at -1,2.5 right
set label "CLOCK" at -1,4.5 right
set xtics in scale .1 4 format ""
set grid
unset ytics
set key at -1,3.75 right
plot 'plotting' using 0:1 every :::$1::$1 title 'Results' with lines lt 1 lw 2,     \
 ''            using 0:2 every :::$1::$1 notitle  with lines lt 1 lw 2,         \
 ''            using 0:3 every :::$1::$1 title 'Expected' with lines lt 3 lw 3, \
 ''            using 0:4 every :::$1::$1 notitle with lines lt 3 lw 3,          \
 ''            using 0:5 every :::$1::$1 notitle with lines lt -1 lw 3
EOF
```

So when I make $1 to be anything from 0 to 26 it gives me multiple plots on one graph. If it's anything from 27 to 99 I know I get only one plot with only the data I want. I can't even find out where the second set of data on those first plots comes from. Sifting through the text in my data file to match it up would be extraordinarily tedious. Any help or advice on how to fix this double graphing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 2 sets of data in them?  It looks like your plots should have 5 sets of data in them ...

Comment: Yeah, there's five lines that get plotted. So by two sets of data, I mean there are 10 lines plotted, with one set of five plotted on top of the other set of five.

Comment: What about the line colors/linetypes?  Are those consistent?  It seems to me that something must have happened to remove a blank line from your datafile or something ... (or added a single blank line -- or you have NaNs in your datafile which you could probably `grep` (`grep -in nan`))